# Python numpy: log10 inside where raises a warning -- invalid value encountered

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scientific-computing

Python's numpy `log10` function gives me a run-time warning if I use it inside numpy `where` function in the following way. By the condition argument to `where`, I make sure that `log10` value is requested only for valid elements. May I safely ignore the warning?

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

print('np.__version__ =',np.__version__)

aa=np.array([3.0,  -5.0])
bb=np.where(aa>0.0, np.log10(aa), -987.00005)
print('bb=', bb)
```

Here is the standard output:

```
$ ./main.py 
np.__version__ = 1.11.0
./main.py:8: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log10
  bb=np.where(aa>0.0, np.log10(aa), -987.00005)
bb= [  4.77121255e-01  -9.87000050e+02]
```

Comment: As per standard Python behavior, the 3 arguments are evaluated (in full) before being passed to the `where` function.  Consider using the `where` parameter of the `np.log10` `ufunc` instead.

Comment: I just noticed a funny thing: If I run `bb=np.where(aa>0.0, np.log10(aa), -987.00005)` twice in python repl, IT WORKS!. First time it shows an error and the next time it works properly.

Comment: @hpaulj If you could post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: @Agile_Eagle It's not an error, it's a warning. And the warning is suppressed the second time, that's all.

Comment: @Agile_Eagle, warnings can be set to be ignored,  displayed the first time only, or displayed always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `where`. You can get the same effect by calling `log10` on its own:

```
>>> aa=np.array([3.0,  -5.0])
>>> np.log10(aa)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/ptipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log10
array([0.47712125,        nan])
```

Or even on a single value:

```
>>> np.log10(-5.0)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/ptipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log10
nan
```

And the reason is simple: negative numbers are invalid values for a [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm). Why? Well, what number is the log of -5? Put another way, what number N could you raise `10**N` and get `-5`? There is no such number. Even for numbers approaching negative infinity, you still get positive numbers appraaching `0`.

So, NumPy warns you about it (and then returns nan).

---

Of course that's only true for real numbers; the complex number `-5` (aka `-5.0 + 0j` in Python terms) does have a logarithm—or, rather, an infinite number of them, but you can define a "principal cut", in which the log is around `0.699 + 1.36i`. And, in fact, NumPy can handle that just fine if you're using complex numbers:

```
>>> bb = np.array([3.0+0j, -5.0+0j, 1+1j])
>>> np.log10(bb)
array([0.47712125+0.j        , 0.69897   +1.36437635j,
       0.150515  +0.34109409j])
```

---

Applying `np.where` after calling `np.log10` isn't going to help. If you want to use `where` here, you have to do it the other way around. For example:

```
>>> np.log10(np.where(aa>0.0, aa, 1e-300))
array([   0.47712125, -300.        ])
```

Of course there is no `np.float64` small enough to give you `-987.00005`, so if you really need that value, and you also really need to use `where`, you'll need a second `where` after the `log10`.

Comment: Thanks, but I know that `log10` is undefined for negative argument. That's why I tried using `where`.

Comment: @norio But you're applying `where` _after_ you apply `log10`, so how do you expect that to help?

Comment: Documentation of `numpy.where` does not specify the order of substitution, evaluation of the condition, that of x, and that of y arguments, i.e., whether "You're applying `where` *after* you apply `log10`".

Comment: @norio NumPy doesn't document the behavior of Python calls in every single function, because all Python calls work the same way. You have a callable, and you have values passed as arguments.

Comment: O.K. So, you mean that, for any python functions `f(x)` and `g(y)`,  the statement `f(g(yy))` is evaluated in the order of `g(yy)` and then `f(xx)`, in which `xx` is the value of `g(yy)`. That makes sense. I withdraw my previous comment.

Comment: @norio Right. This may not be covered that well in the official tutorial, or in many third-party tutorials/courses/books, because they're kind of assuming that if you have any pre-existing intuitions about this, they come from C or a C-descended language, not from, say, Lisp, or Tcl, or (and this is the one that hits people most often) mathematical notation.

Comment: Yes, and I think it's all right not to cover the order of evaluation in the tutorial; that's more or less obvious. I was blinded about this rule only in my particular context in which I was re-writing a for-loop containing an if-else block. Thanks for pointing it out.